# How to combine Hobby paths with PGF Basic Layer commands?

Tags: pgf-core, hobby

I need to combine paths that are created via the [hobby](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package with standard `pgf` path elements, like arcs. Within the Frontend Layer this is easily done, e.g.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\draw (0,0) arc[start angle=180, end angle=90, x radius=1cm, y radius=1cm] .. (0.51, -0.5) .. (0, 0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to construct `hobby` paths within the `pgf` Basic Layer, i.e. for use with `\pgfusepath`, in the documentation of the `hobby` package.
Since there are situations where I prefer path construction via Basic Layer commands I'd like to know: Is there some way of combining `hobby` paths with `pgf` Basic Layer paths into one connected (or closed) path? Does the `hobby` package maybe provide a Basic Layer interface that I haven't found?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `hobby` branches off from PGF syntax by `..` and not having a succeeding `c` of `controls` and accumulates the points in L3 arrays. So it's not a simple low level PGF trickery. Though a low-level branching should also possible, I don't know if Andrew Stacey sees any benefit from that.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the information. I agree that a low-level usage of `hobby` paths will only be needed in some niche cases. Usually the Frontend Layer path construction works well enough for me but when it comes to paths containing elliptic arcs I often depend on the `\pgfpatharcaxes` command.

Comment: Have you tried defining keys that will give you similar behavior to `\pgfpatharcaxes` in the Frontend Layer?

Comment: @CharlesStaats Good suggestion. I've not thought about that yet, because till now `\pgfpatharcaxes` worked well enough for my purposes. I will give it a shot. Nevertheless the question of Basic Layer `hobby` paths is still interesting, e.g. it might be quite handy for defining new decorations where I can't use Frontend Layer commands.

Comment: Hi, I only just found this question.  What would you like `hobby` to do?  It should be possible to provide a "low level" path generated using Hobby's algorithm.  Can you provide an example of what the output _should_ be?  That is, can you add an example of the path construction you use that includes an honest bezier curve.  I should be able to figure out the syntax for `hobby` from that.

Comment: *Re latest edit.*  Ah.  That's because the hobby algorithm needs to know the initial point.  It tries to guess it as the previous `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` but clearly this isn't working in this case.  Not sure what the best thing is to do in this case.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Would it be possible to tell `hobby` the initial point explicitly (maybe as an option to `\pgfpathhobby`) without having to use `\pgfpathmoveto`?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best.  How about an option to _override_ the current method.  So if nothing is specified then it uses the last `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Sounds good. By the way, I just found a work-around for my case: replacing `\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}` with `\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}` works. So `\pgfpathlineto` is recognized correctly.

Comment: Actually, all you need to do is `\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}`.

Comment: Looking at the PGF code, I found where it stores the last coordinate on the path.  I've just updated the code at launchpad to use that.  So that should obviate the need to tell it the initial point.  Please test!  And if you have other ideas for the basic layer interface, let me know.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thank you so much. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that a) I've understood the question, and b) I've done the upload correctly, this is now possible with the development version of `hobby`, which is available from the [TeX-SX launchpad page](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) (download `hobby.dtx` and run `tex hobby.dtx` to generate the files).

(*Update based on comments and clarification*)

The new syntax is as follows.  Start with `\pgfpathhobby` and end with `\pgfpathhobbyend`.  The `\pgfpathhobby` will look to see if it is followed by a `\bgroup` (or `{`) and if so consider the following group as key-value options to be passed on to the configuration.  Each point is specified by `\pgfpathhobbypt{<point specification>}` and will also look for a following group which is taken to be key-values for that point.  As an example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0}}
\pgfpathhobby{closed=true}
\pgfpathhobbypt{\pgfpoint{1cm}{2cm}}{tension in=2}
\pgfpathhobbypt{\pgfpoint{2cm}{1cm}}
\pgfpathhobbypt{\pgfpoint{3cm}{0cm}}
\pgfpathhobbyend
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Obviously, this is still very much in flux and so liable to change.  I'll try to keep this answer up to date with the latest version.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry that my response comes so late. This looks pretty much like what I had in mind. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get your new code working with my MiKTeX distribution in order to test it. I have edited my question to share my thoughts on the syntax. But I don't know much about the inner workings of `pgf` and `hobby` so that my suggestion might not be very practical. But maybe it gives you some ideas that might be helpful. Thanks again for being so quick about implementing a solution to my problem in your package.

Comment: @Philipp See edit.

Comment: Awesome, this syntax is definitely more convenient than what I came up with (I thought there was something preventing the use of keyword arguments in the Basic Layer, that's why my version was so complicated). If I may, I'd like to make some suggestion for the behaviour of those `hobby` Basic Layer commands, because it does behave the way I would have expected. And I still couldn't manage to combine an arc and a Hobby path to a (combined) closed path. See my edit.